# Dynamic website to static: How to serve virtual directory as page and parent

Tags: apache-2.4

Say I have a dynamic website which have virtual directories that are also served as pages.

The dynamic website produces URLs like these:

- home
- categories

  - children pages
- contact

So home is a page, categories are pages under which children reside.

**All pages have chosen name, that cannot be changed.**

I need, temporary, to serve this dynamic website "as static". So I used `wget` to get files.

Finally, I have to use `apache2.4` to serve these pages.

Now, how can I map these categories pages with Apache?

Indeed, if i use real folders to represent the categories pages, I can no more access them (only home, contact and children are reachable).

If I use files to represent the categories pages, I can access them, but I can no more access children…

[I tried to use aliases](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html#outside) (even if I will not have access to `httpd.conf` in production), like this:

- `Alias "/category-1/page" "/home/www/category-1-folder/page"`

But again, categories page are no more reachable…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach should work:

```
www.site.com/home => /var/www/html/home/index.html
www.site.com/categories => /var/www/html/categories/index.html
www.site.com/categories/abc => /var/www/html/categories/abc/index.html
```

Another option would be to use the `Rewrite` module to make internal rewrites on the URLs.

Comment: Thanks!!! Powerfull! I have added `RewriteRule ^(.*\/)$ $1/index [L]` to be usable.